# Third Party alias within Sitecore 8.2

Tags: redirect

When we transferred over to Sitecore the agency that helped us do this used a third party alias/redirect app supposedly within Sitecore to redirect a lot of links from the old website. From what I understand this list of redirects should sit somewhere within Sitecore but I don't know where to find it as it's not within the our current Alias folder. We have no reference to what it was called either.

Sorry if this seems vague, but I'm trying to resolve a fault and are fairly new to Sitecore. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you have templates in the folder /sitecore/templates/User Defined/Url Rewrite ? If so, you're using this module: https://github.com/iamandycohen/UrlRewrite

Answer (score 0):

You could try to see if the 301 redirect module is used for this. It has the redirect config items defined under `/sitecore/system/Modules/Redirect Module/`.

Also take a look at what custom dlls are added in the bin folder and compare to a vanilla sitecore installation. Another place you could look is if there are any custom processors defined in the `<httpRequestBegin>` pipeline, for example using the `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` page

Comment: No redirect module unfortunately. Whatever is in place kicks in before the aliases in sitecore do from what I can figure out from a few tests so far

Comment: If there aren't any custom processors seen using the showConfig.aspx page, you could try to look if there are any rewrite rules directly in web.config or in IIS

Comment: Look for patched processors in you configs, and also search in your cm for the redirect url. It might help.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Sitecore stack exchange!

Redirects in Sitecore are generally implemented using either of the below approaches

1. IIS Rewrite rules - This is implemented on IIS webserver using UrlRewrite Module enabled/installed on IIS. The rules are available within the web.config and are based on redirect maps and regex patterns,
2. Sitecore Redirect Module - You would require a Sitecore marketplace module to be installed on Sitecore. This enables the Content Authors to setup redirect rules. This module if installed on your Sitecore Instance should have a redirect foldes within /sitecore/content